# Are there any apps on Cydia specific to AppleTV?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv, cydia

Just wondering are there any apps specifically for AppleTV on Cydia. I have jailbroken my AppleTV 2 and am looking to install XBMC to get 1080p playback, as well as a browser. Are there any other apps out there? Please let me know.

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps pedantically, I'd like to point out that while you can play back 1080p video through an Apple TV 2, you will still get 720p output. From the [XBMC FAQ](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMC_for_iOS_specific_FAQ):

> At present, though the ATV2 can decode
>   1080p video (using Apple's private
>   VideoToolBox API for
>   hardware-accelerated decoding), it is
>   limited to 720p output. The 1080p
>   video is decoded, then down-scaled in
>   hardware to 720p.

Slightly off-topic, but I find Plex to be a superior Apple TV client to XBMC. I prefer the Plex interface to XBMC. You will, however, need to set up a Plex server, as Plex for iOS is a client that needs to hook up to a server, which does media management and transcoding as needed.